# Same design in VHDL and Verilog. But different speed and resource usages?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, xilinx, hdl

I have two codes, one in Verilog and another in vhdl, which counts the number of one's in a 16 bit binary number. Both does the same thing, but after synthesising using Xilinx ISE, I get different synthesis reports.

**Verilog code:**

```
module num_ones_for(
    input [15:0] A,
    output reg [4:0] ones
    );

integer i;

always@(A)
begin
    ones = 0;  //initialize count variable.
    for(i=0;i<16;i=i+1)   //for all the bits.
        ones = ones + A[i]; //Add the bit to the count.
end

endmodule
```

**VHDL code:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity num_ones_for is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           ones : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0));
end num_ones_for;

architecture Behavioral of num_ones_for is

begin

process(A)
variable count : unsigned(4 downto 0) := "00000";
begin
    count := "00000";   --initialize count variable.
    for i in 0 to 15 loop   --for all the bits.
        count := count + ("0000" & A(i));   --Add the bit to the count.
    end loop;
    ones <= std_logic_vector(count);    --assign the count to output.
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Number of LUT's used in VHDL and Verilog - 25 and 20.
Combination delay of the circuit - 3.330 ns and 2.597 ns.

As you can see the verilog code looks much more efficient. Why is that?

The only difference I can see is, how 4 zeros are appended on MSB side in VHDL code. But I did this, because otherwise VHDL throws an error.

Is this because of the tool I am using, or HDL language or the way I wrote the code?

Comment: The problem is not the language. The tool uses different optimizers for each language front-end. The optimum should be around 13 LUTs.

Comment: @Paebbels Depends on the size of the LUTs...

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, but I assume that he isn't using such old Xilinx devices that use LUT4 instead of LUT6.

Comment: I am using ise 14.6. When I checked the technology schematic after synthesis, its using some LUT4, some LUT5 and some LUT6.  How did you get this number of 13 as optimum?

Comment: Comments: (1) the code is different; re-code the VHDL to use an *integer* variable, like the Verilog, and compare; (2) this is a really bad way to count 1's, and relies on a very smart synthesiser - Google for better ways; (3) it won't affect your result (I hope), but use non-blocking assigns in your Verilog (`<=`).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to try a number of different experiments before coming to any conclusions. But my observation is that Verilog is used more frequently in the most critical capacity/area/performance designs. Therefore the majority of research effort goes into handling Verilog language tools first.

Comment: Then what kind of projects does VHDL used in?

Comment: @dave_59: I would be surprised if a vendor translated directly from the language front-end - they're likely to be translating from an intermediate representation. I did some work 3 or 4 years ago checking Xilinx's XST for various basic structures and FSMs, and the output was almost identical for both languages, with some minor VHDL wins in FSMs. I've done Verilog and VHDL ASICs, and never seen anyone select a language on the basis of QOR.